# Can't turn in power play tokens

Tags: elite-dangerous

I have got myself 70 trade agreements, and was very happy to finally deliver them after 30 slow jumps. But when I arrive, it only gives me the option to nominate the system. It shows three expansion systems, but I can't turn it in in any. Even when I view the system "power status" itself, it prompts me to bring trade agreements to the place. Now my hard work gone to waste since the week seems to end. It's just so disappointing. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: What kind of system are you in? Control, exploit, or HQ?

Comment: They show up under "Expansion" Preparing, "Power view" shows task: turn in trade agreements. I can't tough.

Comment: For what power? (I am used to turning in Crime Sweep vouchers for ALD)

Comment: This is for Mahon. I think it may be bad idea to expand, but I already have them and want to use the tokens so I can rank up.

Comment: Sorry - Preparation, not expansion!! I have checked so many times my mind borked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug that happens sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn in preparation cargo to the power contact at any station in the system you want to prepare. You can't just turn them in at the power status screen in the galaxy map.

Comment: Naw, I know where to turn it in, but thanks for trying!